# Timeout when trying to access QtDBus Objects that where created in a Windows system service

Tags: windows, qt, service, dbus

I want to create a Windows system service using QT/MinGW which communicates with other applications over DBUS (from freedesktop.org). For the moment DBUS is running as a "service" by meaning of it was installed as service using the instsrv/srvany tools (however, the DBUS will get it's bus-service-win later). Since running as a service, DBUS is running as system bus.

I wrote a simple application to ensure that DBUS is working (creates on simple object with 1 method and exectued it with QDBusViewer). Well, that worked.

Next I tried to use the same DBUS stuff in the ServiceMain from my service, where ServiceMain is a member of a class created by our own). I can see the object in QDBusViewer, but as soon as I select it, QDBusViewer reported a timeout (no reply) after it stucked for a while.

I have seen this behavior in my test application, and could fix it by creating a QCoreApplication "app" and "block" on app.exec() after the DBus object have been created. I tried the same in the service, but got a warning that QCoreApplication was not created in the main thread, and the problem still persists.

I tried to create "app" in the function that calls StartServiceControlDispatcher() and run app.exec in the ServiceMain, but app.exec() quits immediately with a the error "must be called from the main thread".

How can I get over this? Have much thanks in before.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing my own service class against the QtService class from "QT Solution" fixed my problem.

All after all I needed to put the StartServiceControlDispatcher() function into a QThread and change the method of my service class in a way that exec() is only executed when definitely running in the context of the SCM.